# frabric js freedrawing, get a reference to the object draw

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

When using fabricjs in free draw mode, you can brush paths. Is there a way to get a reference as object to these paths, immediately after it is drawn? Example on mouse up get the object:

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(options) {
    var lastfreedraw = options.getLastFreeObject();
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Considering the info on [freedraw](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4/#free_drawing) and [events](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events) I would suggest subscribing to the path:created object. Something like

```
canvas.on('path:created', function(e){
    var your_path = e.path;
    // ... do something with your path
});
```

should do.

Comment: Great, thank you, I missed that paragraph. Let say fabrijs is a great library, but has not a good documentation